# attrs library and super

Tags: python, oop, super, python-attrs

Here is a toy example of class that I want to refactor. In reality I've much more parameters/attributes like momentum, so a lot of code repetition:

```
class TransformBl(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, 
                 features,
                 momentum=0.1,
                 **kwargs):        
        super(TransformBl, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.features = features
        self.momentum = momentum
        self.transform = tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.features, use_bias=False)

    def call(self, inputs, training=None):
        x = self.transform(inputs)
        return x
```

I've started to look for solution to avoid repetition and `attrs` library seems to fit. There is no problem with `features`, `momentum` and inheritance.
Unfortunately, I can't find example with construct like `super(TransformBl, self).__init__(**kwargs)` in `__init__`
I've tried with just `super()` but I got `RuntimeError: super(): no arguments`

Is there a way to re-write this class in `attrs` style?

Comment: I suggest using `dataclasses` available since Python 3.7 (also backported to 3.6).

Comment: `dataclasses` provide subset functionality of `attrs` - I need also validators. Anyway, maybe I miss something obvious, but I didn't find any examples of `dataclasses` with `super`.

Comment: There is nothing about validators in your question. With dataclasses you will need to use `__post_init__` method instead of call `super`.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

As of `attrs` 21.1.0, support for both `__attrs_pre_init__` and `__attrs_init__` has been added. Please see [the docs on initialization](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/init.html#hooking-yourself-into-initialization) for details.

The old answer remains true for `attrs` versions older than 21.1.0:

I'm afraid you won't be able to use neither `attrs` nor dataclasses, that have been mentioned for some inscrutable reason.  Neither allow your `__init__` to take `**kwargs` but more importantly, neither will allow you to run `super().__init__()` before setting that instance's attributes because both only have the concept of an **post**-init hook.

And trying to use that will give you a Runtime error because Model intercepts `__setattr__`:

```
RuntimeError: It looks like you are subclassing `Model` and you forgot to call `super(YourClass, self).__init__()`. Always start with this line.
```

`attrs` may grow support for what you want by writing a separate `__attrs_init__` method that you can call yourself from your `__init__`, after running the necessary super: https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs/issues/393

There's no imminent timeline, but issues like this make a good case for it.

In the linked ticket, there's also a rather [elaborate workaround](https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs/issues/393#issuecomment-510148031) that solves a similar problem for PyTorch.